# C# TreeView SetFocus firing leave event twice

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I have this simple code, where when the user leaves the TextBox control, TreeView gets focused:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.treeView1.Nodes.Add("A");
        this.treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("A.A");

        this.treeView1.Nodes.Add("B");
        this.treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("B.A");

    }



    private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Leave..");
        this.treeView1.Focus();
    }
}
```

If we execute this code the Leave event is fired twice:

Leave.. 
Leave..

But if we set focus to other control, only one Leave event is fired.

Is that a problem of the TreeView? Do you know any workaround? Should we report this to Microsoft?

Thanks,
RG

Answer (score 3):

```
    this.treeView1.Focus();
```

Do *not* use the Focus() method in an event handler that's called because of a focusing event, like Leave.  If you need to prevent a focus change then use the Validating event instead.  Setting e.Cancel = true stops it.

But do note that this isn't very logical to do so for a TreeView, there isn't anything the user can do to alter the state of the control.  You'll trap the user.  Maybe that was the intention, do make sure the user can still close the window.  If not then you might need the FormClosing event to force e.Cancel back to false.

Comment: @Joel - at the time Enter and Leave are fired, the focusing logic is in a transitional state.  The logic is difficult because of the Validating event, it can cancel focus changes *after* they  already occurred.  There are more artifacts like this, jerking the focus away with a MessageBox in a Validating event handler causes trouble as well.  And the reason that Enter and Leave exists when there already is GotFocus and LostFocus.  Ugly stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Given that there is no code there to wire up the event I'm guessing you did it from the designer which means a line of code such as

```
textBox1.Leave += new EventHandler(textBox1_Leave);
```

will have been added to the Form1.designer.cs, check this file to ensure the line doesn't exist more than once as for each time this line is run you will get an event trigger, so if you run the line 3 times the Leave event will fire 3 times when you leave the textbox!

HTH

OneShot

Comment: I already have checked that, and the event is only install once.